# How do I show SubReport Headers in the parent report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2010, reportbuilder3.0

I've created 30 individual rdl reports each with a header which contains the report name (H2)

I've then created a cover page which is nothing but a blank template with a header and a footer (H1) and in the body of this cover report I've placed these 30 SubReports and linked the parameters. When I click run, SRSS ignores all of the headers of the SubReports (H2) and only uses the cover header (H1,meaning I lose all of my individual report names)

[image: Cover Report & SubReports connected via parameters]

Is there any way to force SRSS to display the headers within the SubReports as if they were being run individually? or would there be a better method to connect them. Ideally I don't want to put the report title in the body.

Thanks

Comment: where you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @WiiMaxx The header will only show one name for the report so in this instance I placed a text box within the sub report with it's title so when run it then it shows the individual names.

Comment: mhh i ended up with the same work around but there should be a way to use the Header of the SubReport. thx for your answer

Comment: where you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this because when you have subreport in your main report, only subreport's body part is visible.
It is because report can have only one header and footer, so they are taken from main report only.

Workaround is to remove header and footer in your subreport and replace them with textboxes.